# Call vibration trigger.io module

Tags: android, trigger.io

Im trying to create a vibration function for a trigger.io module (new to android/java)

The code I have is below, but i keep getting this

`The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type API`

Am I not importing a library or something?

```
public class API {
    public static void pulse(final ForgeTask task){
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        // Output yes if can vibrate, no otherwise
        if (v.hasVibrator()) {
            v.vibrate(400);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting hold of Context in a Trigger.io module can be done via a call to `ForgeApp.getActivity()`

Which would give you:

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator)ForgeApp.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Got a reply from trigger.io with the same response but thanks this fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to call getSystemService() as you you would from an activity?

You will need to pass the context to do that (can be your activity) and call it on context

For example, you could pass it in the constructor:

```
public class API {

    Context mContext;

    public API(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public static void pulse(final ForgeTask task){
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) mContext.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        // Output yes if can vibrate, no otherwise
        if (v.hasVibrator()) {
            v.vibrate(400);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ah thought i was missing something, I just need to check it now works.

Comment: it does not work it keeps giving ```"type":"UNEXPECTED_FAILURE"``` and ```NullPointerException```

Comment: This is just a general native Android solution, guess it doesn't work with trigger.io :)